# Upgrading PHP to latest version

Tags: php

I've been using **`PHP-5.4.3`** for about a month now, and today, I decided to make a switch to **[PHP-5.5.5](http://www.php.net/get/php-5.5.5.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror)**, I downloaded the source code, and placed it in `C:/php` (*also renaming the folder `php-5.5.5` to `php`*) and I added server variables, as usual `C:/php/` *<-- but here I got stuck*. Because, usually I appended the `php.exe` at the end, which was found inside the PHP folder so, I could be able to access PHP from the command line, or start the built-in server, but now,I can't find this file, and I can't find a way to start the server from the command line either.

Comment: Not sure if this question belongs on SO since it is not related to programming

Comment: @kingkero It is about updating PHP. It is about installing PHP. How programming related can it get?

Comment: @Shomz I just downloaded the source code, from the mirrored link I provided. But, I can not find the executable file

Comment: That's because the source code needs to be compiled... Try something from [here](http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.5) (assuming you're using Windows, of course). Or read [this](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild).

Comment: @Shomz Thanks, I am donwloading it. I'll see it I can make it work now

Comment: @Xlaltra Because the software you are having problems with is for programmers, doesn't mean that questions about the software are programming-related. The question is software-related

Comment: @kingkero Oh, come on. Then let's delete all those git questions asking how to revert last commit? It's not strictly programming question, is it?

Comment: @galymzhan I'd do so. Please don't misunderstand me, I said "not sure if" and didn't downvote

Answer (score 1):

You can compile php yourself. It's simply 2-4 commands and its also explained. I can run configure then make install. You can run configure --help to see all the options. It can be useful if you compile for fast-cgi or need more space or a faster php.

Comment: I just don't understand what compile means, or is supposed to do. Can't I just download it, and run the built-in server, just from the command line? Is that very hard?

Comment: I think that's because it's free? What do you mean with built-in server? Ruby, Python etc. needs to be compiled,too?

Comment: But with PHP5.4.3 I didn't need to do anything, I just downloaded and started using it

Comment: It's the same: because it's free? How do you know it worked? What's phpversion()? Learn to compile...?

Comment: thanks for the help. I will just stick with old version of php. this is not working for m

Answer (score 0):

The source code you downloaded needs to be built...

You can download a binary version from [here](http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.5) (assuming you're using Windows, of course).

Or read [this](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) if you want to build it yourself. There are many other tutorials online.

Comment: I followed the link you gave, and downloaded the php source, however, I still can not find the php.exe file, or how to reference to php from the enviroment variables? Any intake on that?

Comment: Again, the source needs to be built. You need a binary.

Comment: I am confused, I am new to this thing. php5.4.3 used to work for me, without a problem. Isn't there anyway, I can use php5-5.5 with the same approach. I don't even know, how to "build" anything, I am only trying to use the latest version of php

Comment: Yes, there is a way, I'm trying to tell you that all the time, download a binary and install it just like any other software. This one, for example: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.5.5-nts-Win32-VC11-x86.zip
So, source: needs to be built; binary: already built for you

Comment: Thanks for the help, I downloaded the file, and but still can't see the php executable file. I am just too noob for this.

Comment: Are you serious? The zip archive from my previous comment has the php.exe in the root directory. You know how to unpack it, do you?

Comment: Thanks to the smart downvoter, whoever it was...